# VBA put a conditional static timestamp from a 12 months entry sheet and present it on a new spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, conditional-formatting

I'm relatively new to Excel VBA and was thinking of doing an interesting code for a task at work.

I would like to identify the exact time a document is registered as "received" in the sheet1, and keep it static. Sheet1 consist of the general information (A:K) + 12 columns representing months of year 2019 (L:W).

I want excel to set a fix timestamp only when a "1" is entered in the cell. (1=Received, 2= No documents needed that month.)

To improve navigativity, it would be better if the fix timestamp appeared in the same cell in Sheet2, which is identical to Sheet1 (minus the entries in month cells).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myTableRange As Range
    Dim myDateTimeRange As Range

    Set myTableRange = Range("L3:W350")
    If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set myDateTimeRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L:W" & Target.Row)

    If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
    End If
    If (myDateTimeRange.Value = 2) Then
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Empty
    End If
    If IsEmpty(myDateTimeRange.Value) Then
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Empty
    End If

End Sub
```

I have 2 main issues:
-The first is that, currently, I can't transfer informations from sheet1 to sheet2 over 1 column (Setting `Set myTableRange = Range("L3:L350")` and later `Set myDateTimeRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L" & Target.Row)` work, but I can't figure out how to extend this to multiple column (L:W).

The second issue arise when I use `Range.Value = Now` the cell in Sheet2 update every time I click on a cell, not when I actually type an entry. Also, `If myDateTimeRange.Value = 1 Then myDateTimeRange.Value = Now` doesn't create output.

If you can lead me in the right direction, It would save me a lot trial and error.

Comment: Shouldn't that be Worksheet_Change?

Comment: You're checking the value on sheet2 instead of looking at sheet1

Comment: Also what do you mean by `...and keep it fix...`?

Comment: My bad. For clarification, I'm mean static dates.

Comment: I have 2 main issues. The first is that, currently, I can't transfer informations from sheet1 to sheet2 over 1 column (Setting  `Set myTableRange = Range("L3:L350")` and later `Set myDateTimeRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L" & Target.Row)` work, but I can't figure out how to extend this to multiple column (L:W).  The second issue arise when I use `Range.Value = Now` the cell in Sheet2 update every time I click on a cell, not when I actually type an entry. Also,  `If myDateTimeRange.Value = 1 Then myDateTimeRange.Value = Now` doesn't create output.